# Text Field in Android

Tags: android, textfield, android-edittext

I am developing an Android , which has a Text Field.

Every time user presses any key in the text field(EDIT TEXT), I want to to read that in a character variable, perform some action with that variable, and simultaneously empty the text field. In a way, it is a listener to that EditText Field which performs an operation with every key(character) pressed.

Any ideas on how to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Implement and add a TextWatcher to your EditText: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).